# npm run build connection timeout on ubuntu virtualmin server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, npm

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with virtualmin installed.
Latest npm is installed, running a laravel project

Giving me npm run build

> build
> vite build

vite v4.5.2 building for production...
Connection to ****:10000 closed.

Doesn't complete the build, I tried searching up the problem, increased the timeout but nothing works. Just closes connection like 5 seconds into the build

Comment: Can you share more details, like the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase it doesnt give any error message. connection just close when I run that command

Comment: You wrote "giving me error", but there's no error? That sounds strange. What have you tried to gather more details?

Comment: I tried searching up the problem, increased the timeout but nothing works. Just closes connection like 5 seconds into the build

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it